# sort even numbers ascending then odd numbers descending

Tags: c++, sorting

i have to use std::sort() to sort numbers in an array like this:

even numbers ascending and then odd numbers descending

so far i got:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>                                 
#include <vector>                                       

using namespace std;


bool order(int a, int b)                                    
{
    if (a % 2 == 0)
    {
        return a < b;
    }
    else if(a % 2 != 0)
    {
        return b < a;
    }
}
int main()                                              
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 1 };          
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), order);               

}
```

but i cant figure out the correct order algorithm to do so

Comment: You seem to almost got it. You specify what happens with numbers of different oddity, and what happens to two odd numbers. You just miss the rule for two even numbers.

Comment: @CygnusX1: Actually his function doesn't account for the parity of b at all.

Comment: Your ordering can be interpreted in many different ways. What is the expected output when the input is `{ 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 1 }`? You want *all* even  numbers come before *all* odd numbers? That is partitioning, followed by sorting on both partitions separately?

Comment: all even numbers ascending and then all odd numbers descending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (a % 2 == b % 2) { // same parity
    if (a % 2) { // odd descending
         return b < a; 
     } else { // even ascending
         return a < b;
     }
} else { // odd is bigger than even
    return b % 2;
}
```

Comment: Is that going to work with `std::sort`? How can you prove it?

Comment: why dont i need b % 2 != 0 ? or a % 2 == 0?

Comment: am i somehow able to print out the result to check it?

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, it's a valid. To prove it you would show it is irreflexive and transitive.

Comment: @ryanpattison: I think you should add that crucial detail to your answer for readers like me who don't believe in just *working* code which is not same as *correct* code based on maths.

Comment: @mistergreen in many languages including C++ non-zero is true and zero is false. this code chunk is the body of the order function.

Comment: ahh ok - now i understand

Comment: @Nawaz How to write a valid comparison function would probably be better off in a wiki.

Answer (score 2):

With std:

```
std::vector<int> v {2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 1};
auto it = std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int e) { return e % 2 == 0; });

std::sort(v.begin(), it);
std::sort(it, v.end(), std::greater<>{});

// `v` would be now { 2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 1}.
```